# Jquery getting value from a hidden text field

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use jquery to get value from a hidden text field but no success.
This is the javascript function which is adding html to the page dynamically.

```
          function(lng,lat)
          {
             document.getElementsByClassName("BranchDetails").item(0).innerHTML+=""
          +" <div class='Branches'>"
          +"     <div class='DeleteIcon'><img src='../Images/deleteicon.png' width='15' height='15'></div>"

          +"     <div class='BranchName'>"
          +"      <div class='CompanyBranchNameText'>"
          +"          Company Name"
          +"      </div>"


          +"      <div class='EditCompanyBranchName'>"
          +"          <label>Company Name:</label><input type='text' class='EditNameText' >"
          +"          <input type='hidden' class='longitudeVal' value='"+lng+"' /><input type='hidden' class='latitudeVal' value='"+lat+"' />"
          +"      </div>"
          +"      <a href='javascript:void(0)' class='EditNameLink'><p>edit...</p></a>"
          +"    </div>"
          +" </div>";
          }
```

Now I want to get the values of hidden text fields.
So far what i've done is.

```
           $('.Branches').children('.DeleteIcon').click(

        function()
        {
               alert($(this).siblings('.EditCompanyBranchName').children('.longitudeVal').val());
        }
             );
```

But this is returning me an undefined value.
The lng and lat values are being put in the hidden fields successfully i've checked it using alert boxes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is because `.EditCompanyBranchName` is not a sibling of `.DeleteIcon` - it's a child. Try this:

```
$('.Branches').children('.DeleteIcon').click(function() {
    var long = $(this).parent().find('.longitudeVal').val();
    var lat = $(this).parent().find('.latitudeVal').val();
    alert(long);
    alert(lat);
});
```

This will find the `.logitudeVal` and `.latitudeVal` field within the same `.Branches` element as the `.DeleteIcon` which was clicked on.

Comment: but you can see the .DeleteIcon is closing at same place and .EditCompanyBranchName is not coming inside the tags of .DeleteIcon

Comment: wouldn't you need an `each()` on .longitudeVal to get the lat, lng values?

Comment: @RyanFernandes no, because the `find()` will only look for elements within the parent `.Branch`.

Comment: @RyanFernandes how will this help me? the real problem is that i am not getting the proper values although they are getting appended properly.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify your javascript click event, you could set the hidden input with an unique ID and target that ID with Jquery:

**On Your function(lng,lat)**

```
...
<input type='hidden' id="Jquery_latitude" class='latitudeVal' value='"+lat+"' />
...
```

**Now for the '.DeleteIcon' click event:**

```
$('.Branches').children('.DeleteIcon').live("click", function() {
  var lat = $('#Jquery_latitude').val();
  alert(lat);
});
```

**Notes:**
I've set this click event with the [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to allow it to be available for dynamically created elements.

Comment: From the OPs description the code block at the top is being appended x number of times, using an `id` for the field will result in repeated ids, causing your code not to work correctly.

Comment: i cannot directly refer to the hidden field using id because there are multiple fields being generated with the same class so i want to perform operation on click event for that class only that's why $(this) is a must condition for my situation

Comment: Sorry about that, +'d the Rory McCrossan answer since its approach did solve the issue..